# When I try to use scanf with 2 arrays I get an error

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I am trying to use scanf to assign values to 2 arrays, one is for x coordinate, and other one for y, I am using this code for that:

```
for (i1=1;i1<n;i1++) {
scanf ("%f%f",&(arx[i1], ary[i1]));
}
```

but when I execute I get this error:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:11:25: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-       value]
scanf ("%f%f",&(arx[i1], ary[i1]));
                     ^
prog.c:11:16: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
scanf ("%f%f",&(arx[i1], ary[i1]));
```

So I don't know what am I doing wrong here, I am new to C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
scanf ("%f%f",&(arx[i1], ary[i1])); // Not a valid syntax
```

to

```
scanf ("%f%f",&arx[i1], &ary[i1]);
```

You need to apply `&` operator for each of `arx[i1]`and `ary[i1]` otherwise `,` in `(arx[i1], ary[i1])` will be interpreted by compiler as [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) and hence it will return a r-value. And you should know that the operand of unary `&` must be a l-value.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change following in your code----

```
scanf ("%f%f",&arx[i1], &ary[i1]);
```

By using the above statement you may get the 2 value for 2 different array at time for same array indexing value.